# How to wait in R for a complete JSON before using it

Tags: r, json, shiny, jsonparser

**EDIT**

I have a Shiny app where I need to make successive requests to an API. Every request needs the preceding one to be completed to prevent the `not all data was parsed (0 chars were parsed out of a total of 160 chars` error.

I use requests like `fromJSON(content(GET('https://...')), as = "text"))` with the httr package or `curl_fetch_memory(fromJSON('https://...'))` with the curl package. Unfortunately, when running successive JSON requests, I'm almost always getting the error that not all data was parsed. I'm obliged to pause the system with `Sys.sleep(quite_a_long_time)` to prevent the error. But this is of course not optimal.

How could I make sure the data is ready before going on ? I know there is some callback functions that can be implemented somewhere, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

EDIT:
I'm using a GET request inside a function that is called in a lapply(). Maybe the problem arises because of successive new GET request as in a for loop ? Is there a need to make different sessions ?

Here is what I tried:

```
pgkbData <- reactive({
    
    # current dci filtered 
    #drugs_tmp <- dciCypInput()$x$data$Molécule # dciCypInput is made of a datatable containing drugs name
    #drugs_tmp <- dci_all_en %>% # dci_all_en is made of a dataframe containing french-english translated drug names
      filter(fr %in% drugs_tmp) %>% 
      pull(en)
    drugs_tmp <- c('acenocoumarol', 'tacrolimus') # for reproducible example
    drugs <- stri_trans_general(str = drugs_tmp, id = "Latin-ASCII") # removes accents
    drugs <- gsub(" ", "%20", drugs) # Convert white spaces to %20 to make it compatible with URL
    genes <- genoCypInput()$x$data$Enzyme

    if (length(drugs) == 0 | length(genes) == 0) {
      alert('...')
    }

    drug_id_json <- lapply(drugs, fn_pgkb_drug_id) # defined in separate .R file
    drug_ids <- sapply(drug_id_json, function(item) item$data[[1]]$id) # extract the ids

    gene_id_json <- lapply(genes, fn_pgkb_gene_id) # find genes IDs
    gene_ids <- sapply(gene_id_json, function(item) item$data[[1]]$id) # extract the ids

    drugs_genes <- expand_grid(drugs, genes)  # all drug-gene combinations
    drugsId_genesId <- expand_grid(drug_ids, gene_ids) # all drug-gene ids combinations
    final_df <- cbind(drugs_genes, drugsId_genesId)
    total <- nrow(final_df)
    
    for (source in c('cpic', 'dpwg')) { # look for CPIC and DPWG guidelines
      guidelines_json <- lapply(1:nrow(drugs_genes), # syntax to apply with multiple arguments
                                function(i) fn_pgkb_guideline(drug_id = drugsId_genesId$drug_ids[i],
                                                              drug = drugs_genes$drugs[i],
                                                              gene_id = drugsId_genesId$gene_ids[i],
                                                              gene = drugs_genes$genes[i],
                                                              source = source,
                                                              total = total,
                                                              i = i)) 
      guidelines_status <- sapply(guidelines_json,
                                  function(item) item$status) # e.g., 'fail', 'success',...
      guidelines_summary <- sapply(guidelines_json,
                                   function(item) item$data[[1]]$summaryMarkdown$html)
      guidelines_summary[sapply(guidelines_summary, function(x) length(x) == 0L)] <- NA # Replace NULL values with NA to keep a 6-element vector (otherwise NULL are dropped with unlist())

      # urls <- sapply(guidelines_json, function(item) item$data[[1]]$crossReferences[[1]]$resourceId)
      urls <- sapply(guidelines_json, function(item) {
        if (length(item$data[[1]]$crossReferences) > 0) {
          return(item$data[[1]]$crossReferences[[1]]$resourceId)
        } else {
          return(NA)
        }
      })
      
      # guidelines_url <- lapply(urls, function(url) HTML(paste0("<a href='", url, "' target='_blank'>Voir recommendation</a>")))
      guidelines_url <- lapply(urls, function(url) {
        if (!is.na(url)) {
          link_text <- "Voir recommandation"
          link_html <- HTML(paste0("<a href='", url, "' target='_blank'>", link_text, "</a>"))
          return(link_html)
        }
        else {
          return("")
        }
      })
      
      final_df <- final_df %>% 
        cbind(status = guidelines_status,
              source = unlist(guidelines_summary),
              lien = unlist(guidelines_url))
    }
    names(final_df)[5] = "status_CPIC"
    names(final_df)[6] = "CPIC"
    names(final_df)[7] = "lien (CPIC)"
    names(final_df)[8] = "status_DPWG"
    names(final_df)[9] = "DPWG"
    names(final_df)[10] = "lien (DPWG)"
    final_df <- final_df %>% 
      filter(status_CPIC == 'success' | status_DPWG == 'success')
    datatable(final_df,
              #extensions = c("Buttons"), 
              rownames = FALSE,
              filter = 'top', 
              selection = "none",
              editable = FALSE,
              escape = FALSE,
              options = list(
                #   search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE),
                pageLength = 20,
                dom = 'lftipr'
                #   buttons = list(list(extend = "copy", text = '<span class="fa-solid fa-copy"></span> Copier', title = ''))
                #
              )
    )
  })
```

**custom methods in separate .R file:**

```
pgkb_get_prefix <- 'https://api.pharmgkb.org/v1/data/'

pgkb_drugId_url <- function(chemical_name) {
  url <- paste0(pgkb_get_prefix, 'chemical?name=', chemical_name)
  return(url)
}

fn_pgkb_drug_id <- function(chemical_name) {
  pgkb_drug_id <- content(GET(paste0(pgkb_get_prefix,
                                     'chemical?name=',
                                     chemical_name)))
  short_notification(duration = 0.8, message = paste0('ID (', chemical_name, ') (1/3)'))
  Sys.sleep(0.8)
  return(pgkb_drug_id)
}

fn_pgkb_gene_id <- function(hgng_gene) {
  pgkb_gene_id <- content(GET(paste0(pgkb_get_prefix,
                                     'gene?symbol=',
                                     hgng_gene)))
  short_notification(duration = 0.8, message = paste0('ID (', hgng_gene, ') (2/3)'))
  Sys.sleep(0.8)
  return(pgkb_gene_id)
}

fn_pgkb_guideline <- function(drug_id, drug, gene_id, gene, source, total, i) {
  result <- content(GET(paste0(pgkb_get_prefix,
                               'guidelineAnnotation?source=',
                               source,
                               '&relatedChemicals.accessionId=',
                               drug_id,
                               '&relatedGenes.accessionId=',
                               gene_id)))
  
  Sys.sleep(1)
  status <- result$status
  short_notification(duration = 1, message = paste0(drug, ' / ', gene, ' (', source, ') '))
  short_notification(duration = 1, message = paste0('Status: ', status, ' (', i, '/', total, ')'))
  # if (status == "fail") {
  #   error <- result$data$errors[[1]]$message
  #   print(paste('error =', error))
  # }

  return(result)
}
```

I read on the API documentation that only 2 requests per second are allowed (this is probably the reason why I have sometimes no data back - if more than 2 requests reach the API within one second - and why I will have to pause the system). The idea would be to pause for 0.5 seconds once data from the previous request is available to make sure I use Sys.sleep() for the minimal time that would be necessary.

Comment: if you could share some of your code, that would be great! :-)

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]) and/or inputs/controls for using the shiny app, and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Could this be about shiny reactivity chains?

Comment: Please provide reproducible code.

Comment: Thank you all. Sorry for not getting back earlier. I tried to provide a minimal reproducible example, hoping I did not forget something. I noticed that requests are limited to 2 per second, meaning I will have to pause the system for 0.5 seconds after I receive data back I suppose ? But knowing when data is received would allow me to know when pausing for 0.5, am I right ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with `curl_multi_fetch`:

```r
library(curl)

pool <- new_pool()

# callback
cb <- function(req){cat("done:", req$url, ": HTTP:", req$status, "\n")}

# multi fetch
curl_fetch_multi('https://www.google.com', done = cb, pool = pool)
curl_fetch_multi('https://cloud.r-project.org', done = cb, pool = pool)
curl_fetch_multi('https://hb.cran.dev/blabla', done = cb, pool = pool)

out <- multi_run(pool = pool)
# done: https://cloud.r-project.org/ : HTTP: 200 
# done: https://www.google.com/ : HTTP: 200 
# done: https://hb.cran.dev/blabla : HTTP: 404
```